# Merge Request for trio [dnsbl] [dnsrbl] [rbl]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

These three tags should be merged

- [rbl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rbl) (30) a.k.a Real-time Blackhole List
- [dnsbl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dnsbl) (5) a.k.a. DNS-based Blackhole List
- [dnsrbl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dnsrbl) (3) a.k.a. DNS-based Real-time Blackhole List

RBL and DNSBL was interchangeable each other. DNSRBL was a combination between those two.

Still I'm unsure which tag should be synonym to the other. Based on question tagged, RBL was more popular than DNSBL, although DNSBL should be seen as a [more accurate technical term](http://www.rblmon.com/blog/what-are-rbls-and-how-do-they-work/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've merged and synonymized [dnsbl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dnsbl) and [dnsrbl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dnsrbl) into [rbl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rbl), since RBL is the most commonly used term.

Comment: Hi, when researching for tag-wiki content, many resources (for example [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:DNSBL#NPOV_violation), [3](http://www.rblmon.com/blog/what-are-rbls-and-how-do-they-work/), [4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5782), [5](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists), [6](http://www.exim.org/howto/rbl.html)) point out that we should use DNSBL instead RBL for the 'master' tag. Some reason is RBL was 'trademark' of MAPS and DNSBL should be seen as a more accurate technical term.

Answer (score 4):

Happily, we have synonyms for a reason! This is a good request. HopelessN00b will get it done shortly.